# Get total number of lines of code?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Does anyone know if it is possible to get the total number of lines of code from all the classes in my project in Objective-C.
Right now I am guessing that this is not possible but I just wanted to make sure.
If it is possible does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you like the terminal and have all your files in the same folder, try:

```
$ wc *.m
```

To get at the number in your code, you could run it as a shell script build phase that generates a header file for you. E.g.

```
cd source_folder
wc -l *.m \
| tail -1 \
| awk '{ print "#define kNumberOfLines " $1 }' \
> lines_of_code_header.h
```

Then include that file and use the constant as you like.

Comment: I want to know the # of lines of code in code. This will be presented in a UILabel in the app.

Comment: Mats answer still applies. Just run the 'wc' inside an NSTask, and parse the result: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @CraigOtis `NSTask` isn't availabe on iOS, is it?

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer No, but neither is his Xcode project, so I don't know why he would be counting LOC on an iOS device anyway, unless I misunderstood the question. His mention of a UILabel has me confused, as his original question didn't mention anything about iOS.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -name "*.[mh]" -exec wc -l '{}' \; | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
```

Comment: This would be better with some explanation of how it works.  Just dumping code here doesn't teach people anything.

Comment: In fact, there's a good chance this will be deleted if you don't add some detail.